# string related question with numbers included

Tags: python, string, numbers

I would like to **split M22** (so split the string M and the number 22)

I tried finding help from the internet, but most solutions are too complicated too begin with.

Comment: Is there always one lettre and 2 digit ?

Comment: Indeed, is it always M and 22? You should provide more information on what the data will look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always : 1 letter 2 digit, just slice the string

```
v = "M22"
letter, digits = v[0], v[1:]
print(letter, digits) # M 22
```

If the amount of each is variable, use a regex

```
import re
v = "M22"
letter, digits = re.search("([A-Z]+)(\d+)", v).groups()
print(letter, digits) # M 22
```